# Android Compose fillMaxWidth issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Why the width of red circle equal to with of gray area?

Here are my code and result, Hope someone answers.

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun testContent() {
    Scaffold { paddingValues ->
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier

                    .fillMaxWidth(1f)
                    .aspectRatio(0.8f)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(size = 6.dp))
                    .background(Color.Gray)

                    .fillMaxWidth(0.8f)
                    .aspectRatio(ratio = 1f)
                    .clip(CircleShape)
                    .background(Color.Red),

                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "I am text",
                    color = Color.White,
                )
                Text(
                    text = "I am text too",
                    color = Color.White,
                )
            }

        }
    }
}
```

result is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUUNM.png

Answer (score 0):

Because in Column  Composable (which draws/clips red circle) you have a parameter Modifier.fillMaxWidth(1f), thus it takes the maximum width of the parent

1f is is a fraction parameter and if you make it less it will take less width